# Forward port 80 and 443 to external domain using conditional forwarders

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a domain abc.com which is also the address of the external website. Now we have the issue that we can reach the external website when we enter www.abc.com, but not abc.com. We tried to educate the users to use the www. but that doesn't work out. So I'm looking for other ways to solve this issue.
I read that an easy solution is to install IIS on the DC (we have just one) and setup an forward. But with installing IIS on the DC you add more surface for attacks which is a security issue. 
Now I wonder if there is no other way than to install IIS to forwards requests on the ports 80 and 443 for example with a DNS rule? Or maybe a conditional forwarder who just forwards requests for the selected ports?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're stuck now dealing with the ramifications of a poor design decision. :( Installing IIS and configuring it with a redirect is *the* canonical way to solve this problem. There are no DNS tricks you can use, as DNS has no idea about ports not HTTP requests.

You're smart to question the wisdom of installing IIs on your domain controller (aside: WTF do you only have one Domain Controller? That is bound to cause you much bigger problems than IIS is), but at this point, that's a risk you're going to need to take. Ensure that IIS is configured securely and that it's not exposing any more data than it needs to.

Your alternative is to rename the domain, which will be painful, but something you should strongly consider. Only having one Domain controller at the moment makes me think that this is a small organization, so perhaps a rename wouldn't be too arduous to complete.

Comment: yes it is a small company, (around 10 - 15 user) which is also the reason, why there is just one DC. So probably that would really be the best solution..

Comment: You should still have a backup DC! I realize that, for a small company, investing on another server might be too expensive. Therefore, I've recommended a smart **workaround** as Azure capacity for _storage_ and _network_ is extremely cheap and server licenses are expensive: 1) Install your local physical server as a Hyper-V host. 2) Install your DC as a Hyper-V virtual machine and 3) _replicate_ it (the images) to Azure. It won't be another DC, but you'll have a real-time backup that can be booted on Azure during hardware failure. You'll also be ready for an instant cloud migration at anytime.

Comment: That is a very smart idea! We currently use ESXi and a virtual DC. I have to check if there is a similar solution to that with ESXi :)

Answer (score 1):

Now that you already use your external domain as an AD domain, there's nothing else to do, as described in EEAA's answer.  The real solution would be not to use `example.com` as an AD domain, but a sub-domain e.g. `ad.example.com` for that purpose.

If you decide to change your AD domain name, I'd like to **warn you** of the another *widely used* but *inferior* solutions:

- buying a different domain, e.g. `example.org`. I consider that as unnecessary waste of money.
- using non-registered `example.local`. With this, you can never use signed TLS certificates.

Also read TechNet Article: [AD: Best Practices for Internal Domain and Network Names](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34981.active-directory-best-practices-for-internal-domain-and-network-names.aspx).